# Rails Controller - Time , Condition and Geocoder Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am struggling to amalgamate this two statements. I am working on an event app.  I would like to block my users from publishing the events themselves. In order to do that i have a field in my table called "State" and i am also using the geocoder gem.

```
def index
if params[:search].present?
    @events = Event.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance).where(:state => ['3', '4'])
  else
    @events = Event.where('until > ?', Time.zone.now) 
  end
end
```

I would like to do this....

```
def index


 if params[:search].present?
    @events = Event.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance).where(:state => ['3', '4'])
  else
    @events = Event.where('until > ?', Time.zone.now, :state => ['3', '4']) 
  end
end
```

but i get an error

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid in EventsController#index

wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1) in: until > ?
```

Can you please help.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only one placeholder '?', but you supply two arguments. You could do:

```
@events = Event.where('until > :time and state in :state', {:time => Time.zone.now, :state => ['3', '4']})
```

or

```
@events = Event.where('until > ?', Time.zone.now).where(:state => ['3', '4'])
```

or

```
@events = Event.where(:until.gt => Time.zone.now, :state => ['3', '4'])
```

Comment: thank you very much, i am using the second one. Works fine. Have a great day.